# c function "expression of incompatible type error"

Tags: c, types

```
int GreedyArm(const Arm armArray[], int numArms) {
    
    int max= armArray[0];  // initializing 'int' with an expression of incompatible type const Arm'
    for(int i =1; i<numArms; i++){
        if(max < armArray[i])
        {
            max = armArray[i];
        }
    }
    return max; 
}
```

Comment: Arm struct.nitializing 'int' with an expression of incompatible type 'const BanditArm' (aka 'const struct Arm_struct')

Answer (score 2):

What is the type Arm? It appears from the error message that the type is a struct (i.e. struct Arm_struct {....}). max is declared to be an int. You can't assign a structure to an int.

Since GreedyArm returns int, I assume it is supposed to return the index of the item you are using. So use max = 0, and then compare armArray[max].somefield < armArray[I].someffield

Comment: its struct type

Comment: You have to compare a field of the type then. You can't assign a struct to an int.  See the second part of try answer (I was probably editing it when you replied). Also, you appear to be calculating a min when the name is max.

Answer (score 1):

`const Arm armArray[]` is an Arm. `int max` is an int. They are not the same.